# How do I get a specific string out of enum?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I got this exercise in python to create a random amount of circles in tkinter and do stuff with it, it doesn't matter what tho. The main problem is that when I want to create an instance of a certain circle, I also have to randomly choose a color. That would be no problem if I was given a list (which I desperately created myself later on) and just choose a number between random.randint(0, len(list)-1). But our teacher created a class for us and I just don't know how to actually get a single color from it. Tried everything, googled for anything possible, yet no answers showed up. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

Code:

```py
class Colors(Enum):
    BLUE = 'blue'
    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    GREY = 'grey'
    YELLOW = 'yellow'


#method of another class
def someMethod(self):
    #calculations for coordinations etc. would be here, which is unimportant for my question
    #below you can see the temporary solution with list, not using that enum class Colors
    color = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'grey', 'yellow']
    FallDownAtom(x, y, rad, color[random.randint(0, len(color)-1)], random.randint(3, 6), 
                 random.randint(3, 6)))
```

Comment: Not sure about `Enum` but `IntEnum` has a `.value` attribute. Since you are using strings, you might as well not use an enum.

Comment: We were told to have the pre-written code as it is.

Comment: I just looked. You can use `Colors.BLUE.value and Colors.BLUE.name`

Comment: If you want a random enum, you can simply do `random.choice(list(Colors))`

Comment: If you read my last comment then it will answer your question. Your question title and question description ask different questions.

Comment: I put it in the method like this (it is from another file called playground)
```py
random.choice(list(playground.Colors))
```
and right after the first choice it threw this:
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "Colors.GREY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comments to an answer.

```
import random

from enum import Enum

class Colors(Enum):
    BLUE = 'blue'
    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    GREY = 'grey'
    YELLOW = 'yellow'

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, val):
        if val in cls._value2member_map_:
            return cls(val)

        return None


print(Colors.BLUE.name) # BLUE
print(Colors.GREEN.value) # green - String value of the enum

print(random.choice(list(Colors))) # Random enum

print(Colors.get("grey")) # Colors.GREY
```

Your question title and description are different so I put in multiple calls.

### Edit

Error: `...first choice it threw this: _tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "Colors.GREY"` - This is becuase you are using an Enum, not a string. You need to use the `.value` attribute to get the Enum string.

Comment: what actually helped was this
```py
random.choice(list(playground.Colors)).value
```